# "Incompatible types" when assigning struct var to retval of function

Tags: c, function, types, struct, return

I have a function that returns a struct (not a struct pointer), but when trying to set the return value to a struct variable of the same type, I get "incompatible types."

This is what the struct definition and function implementation look like:

```
typedef struct{
    int ssn;
    char FirstName[12];
    char LastName[12];
    int income;
} MyRecord;

MyRecord parseNextRecord()
{
    MyRecord record;
    // parse and initialize
    return record;
}
```

And this is me calling it from within my main function:

```
MyRecord nextRecord;
nextRecord = parseNextRecord(); // "error: incompatible types in assignment"
```

Really stumped about this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you give full error message? Does it mention `int`?

Comment: That is the full error message. It does not mention `int`.

Comment: Is `parseNextRecord()` prototype known by your main ?

Comment: I have the .c file in which the function is implemented in the Makefile, and the .h file in which the struct is defined #included.

Comment: @n00neimp0rtant, the header file also requires the declaration of the `parseNextRecord()` function. Otherwise, the compiler uses an implicit declaration for `parseNextRecord()` with a return type of `int`.

Comment: @hmjd I dunno about everyone else, but post that as an the answer and I'll certainly upvote it. The header doesn't *need* the prototype, but there must be one prior to the call (at the top of the .c file is fine as well). if this is used in multiple .c files, then the header is the obvious choice for where to put it. if not, then a static proto at the top of the .c file is sufficient.

Comment: @WhozCraig, agreed but the header does seem the most sensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the header file, the probable cause is that `main()` does not see a declaration of the `parseNextRecord()` function which results in the compiler generating an implicit declaration for it, with a return type of `int`. This will cause the *incompatible assignment* error as it is not possible to assign an `int` to a `MyRecord`. To resolve, add declaration to the header file:

```
extern MyRecord parseNextRecord();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did it. By the way, is the `extern` necessary? Seems to be compiling just fine without it.

Comment: @n00neimp0rtant No it isn't needed. The standard allows prototypes without it (and has for a *long* time now).